# Is there any way to manage onPanResponderMove?

Tags: react-native

Hello I'm working on react native and I have this code to manage a drag & drop on a element

```
 this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove :
      Animated.event([null, {
      dx: this.state.pan.x,
      dy: this.state.pan.y
    }]), 
.
.
.
```

The thing is that I want to be able to manage the Animated.event pass through the onPanResponderMove when I press a button

Something like

> If I press a button then OnPanResponderMove so I can use drag & drop

I don't really know how I can do it. Has anybody any key on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but probably you can just edit the       `onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true`. Right now it always returns `true` but as the function name says maybe you must return wether you like to enable it or not.

So the solution should be something like this:

```
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: function () {
   return this.state.panResponderEnabled
}
```

And else where you have a button with an `onPress` property (or anything alike) where you can actually change the state.